# Preventing auto graphic rescaling

Tags: graphics

I would like do do something with dynamically updated graphics similar to:

```
square[t_] := Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], t]];
Manipulate[GraphicsRow[{Graphics[Circle[]], square[t]}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

However, what I want is the size of the square to be constant as it rotates while also not adjusting the size of the frame so that the relative sizes of the two shapes also remain constant. How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility is to include an invisible (here visible for clarity) circle behind the square.

```
square[t_] := 
  Graphics[{Thin, Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[2]], Black, 
    Rotate[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], t]}];
Manipulate[GraphicsRow[{Graphics[Circle[]], square[t]}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `PlotRange`.

```
pr = {{(1 - Sqrt[2])/2, (1 + Sqrt[2])/2}, {(1 - Sqrt[2])/
     2, (1 + Sqrt[2])/2}};

square[t_] := Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], t], PlotRange -> pr];
Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow[{Graphics[Circle[{1/2, 1/2}, .5], PlotRange -> pr], 
   square[t]}], {t, 0, 10}]
```